# MSSQL Dynamical Variable Assignment in Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

For some reasons I have to collect data from two related tables:

```
SELECT
    Company.id AS CompanyID,
    Company.name AS CompanyName,

    -- Get New Project ID
    convert(numeric,(CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('"new_project";s:1:"1"',CompanyInfo.data) > 0
        THEN (SELECT TOP(1) Project.id FROM Project
            WHERE Project.Company_id=Company.id
                AND (CAST(Project.CreateDate AS DATE)=CAST(CompanyInfo.date AS DATE)))
        ELSE NULL END
    )) as NewProjectID,

    -- Get New Project Name:
    (CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('"new_project";s:1:"1"',CompanyInfo.data) > 0
        THEN (SELECT TOP(1) Project.name FROM Project
            WHERE Project.Company_id=Company.id
                AND (CAST(Project.CreateDate AS DATE)=CAST(CompanyInfo.date AS DATE)))
        ELSE NULL END
    ) as NewProjectName,

    -- Get New Project Owner:
    (CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('"new_project";s:1:"1"',CompanyInfo.data) > 0
        THEN (SELECT TOP(1) Project.owner FROM Project
            WHERE Project.Company_id=Company.id
                AND (CAST(Project.CreateDate AS DATE)=CAST(CompanyInfo.date AS DATE)))
        ELSE NULL END
    ) as NewProjectOwner,

    ..........................
    -- Gets are go on like those above...
    -- Because MSSQL never merges sub-select results with main select result...
    ..........................

FROM 
    CompanyInfo
LEFT JOIN
    Company ON Company.id=CompanyInfo.Company_id
```

Gets are go on like those above, because MSSQL never merges sub-select results with main select result...

SQL Server doesnt let me to use "NewProjectID" alias as like a variable in select block:

```
SELECT

    -- Get New Project ID once:
    convert(numeric,(CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('"new_project";s:1:"1"',CompanyInfo.data) > 0
        THEN (SELECT TOP(1) Project.id FROM Project
            WHERE Project.Company_id=Company.id
                AND (CAST(Project.CreateDate AS DATE)=CAST(CompanyInfo.date AS DATE)))
        ELSE NULL END
    )) as NewProjectID,

    -- and use it for other subqueries:
    (SELECT Project.name FROM Project WHERE Project.id=NewProjectID) as ProjectName,
    (SELECT Project.owner FROM Project WHERE Project.id=NewProjectID) as ProjectOwner,
    (SELECT Project.addy FROM Project WHERE Project.id=NewProjectID) as ProjectAddy,
...........
```

I've tried many things like:

```
DECLARE @ProjectID int ;

SELECT
    -- Get New Project ID once:
    (@ProjectID = convert(numeric,(CASE
        .............
    ))) as NewProjectID,
.............
```

But I got errors, I lost in errors, I see only errors...

**How to solve that?**

*PS: *CompanyInfo.data column has PHP style serialized datas and I have no permission to redesign table structures...*

Comment: Why not just generate a project id using an identity column? That is what the purpose is for, rather than what you appear to be doing here to generate a new ID manually (I think?).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @jarlh As a programmer you must be already know that not every problem could be written in a simple way. As you see it is a very complex problem. If it is too complex and long for you you can leave silently, you have right to leave, please leave it for others.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @IvanStarostin http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-be-so-obsessive